# Go to record based on unbounded textbox value Ms Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

Hello all I am trying to load my current form based on a textbox, well 2 textboxes.

If the value in textbox1 (which is numeric) is not found I set the focus to textbox2 so I can load the record by name.

This part works for textbox1

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Private Sub Form_Load()
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
End Sub

Private Sub textbox1_AfterUpdate()
If (Me.textbox1 & vbNullString) = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
    rs.FindFirst "[UPC]=" & Me.textbox1
        If rs.NoMatch Then
            Me.textbox2.SetFocus
        Else
            Me.Recordset.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
        End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Close()
rs.Close
End Sub
```

This is not working

```
Private Sub textbox2_AfterUpdate()
    rs.FindFirst "[ITEMNAME] Like '*" & Me.textbox2 & "*'"
        If rs.NoMatch Then
           Me.pmItem.SetFocus
        Else
            Me.Recordset.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? IS there an error message? Does it return NoMatch?

Comment: Do you need to go back to the first record?

Comment: When I enter the product name, nothing happens. The form does not jump to that record. On textbox1 if I enter 10, the form goes to record 10 but if I enter "Soda" in textbox2 nothing happens. It should go to the first record with "Soda" ItemName

Comment: ITEMNAME is a text field?

Comment: ITEMNAME - Text, UPC - Numeric

Comment: Then code should work. Have you step debugged?

Comment: Ok, I added textbox2 to the watchlist. I made a huge error, textbox2 has 2 columns the PK and the ItemName. This line `rs.FindFirst "[ITEMNAME] Like '*" & Me.textbox2 & "*'"` should be `rs.FindFirst "[ITEMNAME] Like '*" & Me.textbox2.Column(1) & "*'"`

Comment: Then it is not a textbox but a listbox or combobox.

Comment: I don't know where my mind was. Sorry for wasting everyone's time.